# videojs player.duration returns 0 on android 4.2 and below

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Hi i'm working on a player using videojs https://github.com/videojs/video.js and I want to get the video player duration

```
player.on( 'loadedmetadata', function() {
 console.log(player.duration()) //returns 0 on android 4.2
})
```

the duration() method is working well for me on android 4.4 and other browsers but it return a duration of 0 on android 4.4 below.

Is there another way to get the duration?